# InfoPath form gets redirected to another SharePoint list after submission

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, drop-off-library

I have a customer who uses infopath forms to create list items. When a new form is created that select a category which has a corresponding folder in the list library. We've worked with them for awhile, and have add new categories before without any issue.

Now I'm facing an issue when the form is submitted instead of submitting to the new folder it get's redirected to a document library called Drop Off Library (content organizer is not enabled).

I've created a new category in the the InfoPath form and an associated folder in the list (same as I always do). In the InfoPath form created a new data connection to the folder using:

`Create a new connection to > Submit data > To a document library on SharePoint site > Enter exact folder path, variable for filename, allow overwrite,`

Once the data connection is created I then add a Form Submit rule. To check when a specific category is selected, then I add a submit data action and use the data connection for that category.

So a normal run through would look like this.

1. New Item
2. Select Category E
3. Enter Info
4. Click Submit
5. Form gets Submitted to Category E folder

I have found the redirect issue is only affecting the new categories we have created all the old categories are functioning correctly.

Does another know why an InfoPath Form would not be submitting correct folder, but instead be redirected to the Drop Off Library?

**EDIT ISSUE Resolved**

With the aid of @ramanaviswanadha. I was able to troubleshoot the issue and discover a generic submit rule had be created that would submit the forms to the "Drop Off Library" before the new category submit rules ran and then it would stop all other rules from running. I deleted this rule and everything is not running with no issues

Comment: Is your submit data connection dynamic? Or do you have different data connections for the different categories?

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha they are individual data connections for each category.

Comment: Okay so for testing purposes alter one of the older data connections to point to a new category folder and see the old connection works still?

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha I was able to change an old data connection and get it to create a new folder. I also attempted recreating the new data connection and still had no luck.

Comment: Okay so modifying the old connection to create a folder works? DO you have conditional rules set up on your submit button to decide which data connection to use? Can you check to see if those conditions are being triggered for the new categories?

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha The only condition on the submit button is to disable button if you don't have a category selected. otherwise when submitted it just uses the data connection associated to a category to determine the location to submit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39190/discussion-between-ramana-viswanadha-and-zingwing).

Comment: You should post the resolution as an answer. Then you can mark is as resolved